# Nesting parameters with ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I want to nest the parameters sent to the backend server. So far my current resource looks like

```
  angular
    .module('myApp.users')
    .factory('User', user);

  user.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function user($resource) {
    return $resource('/users.json');
  }
```

In my controller...

```
var user = new User({name: 'jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com'});
user.$save()
```

The params sent to my backend server end up looking like

```
{name: 'jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com'}
```

Ideally, I want the params sent to the backend server to look like

```
 {user: {name: 'jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com'}}
```

I know that in the controller I can write

```
var user = new User({user: {name: 'jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com'}});
```

However, I don't like that approach. What I want to know is, is there a way to create nested parameters in the User resource and not in the controller. Can the paramsDefault argument help here?

Comment: You should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744611/angularjs-transform-data-before-send-with-ng-resource-and-transformrequest) post. Try to use transform request. And [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is the official docs for that

Comment: I'll look into this. That said, I really enjoy the brevity I have with the $resource object: `return $resource('/users.json');`. If I can prevent myself from having to manually create different resource actions such as update and create, my work would be stellar.

Comment: How about using a service? Have you considered it?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2015/05/07/InterceptAngularjsResourceRequest.aspx

Comment: @EvertonSantos I've thought about it. That said, it adds complexity to my code. I would almost rather just tolerate the problem then build a service to solve it.

Comment: @VaibhavBansal Although that may help, there must be another way to add options to my resource object without custom building the actions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, you should be able to wrap/map input data using the *transformRequest* property: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Try following code:

```
function user($resource) {
  var actions = {
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter){
      return {
        user: data
      }
    }
  }
  return $resource('/users.json',{},actions)
}
```

See as well this question and answers explaining similar solution: [Angularjs: Transform data before send with ng-resource and transformRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744611/angularjs-transform-data-before-send-with-ng-resource-and-transformrequest)

Comment: My interpretation of the docs tells me that I can apply transformReques only to specific actions. For example, in the SO question you provided they had transformRequest INSIDE the update action. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a prototype method to User constructor function

```
app.factory('User', function ($resource) {
        var User = $resource('/users.json');

        // add custom method below 
        User.prototype.getSpecificUser = function() {
            return new User({user: {name: 'jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com'}});
        };
        return User;
    });
```

In your Controller

```
User.getSpecificUser()
```

Comment: I would prefer not to make things overly complicated by generating a new factory.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about writing a simple wrapper for `$resource` ? I have set up [an example plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8zlWbND6vSYUWSnTvgkp?p=preview):

The idea is to pass desired namespace to the wrapper and then just extend each action with `transformRequest` function:

```
app.factory('myResource', function($resource) {
  return function(namespace, url, paramDefaults, actions, options) {
    var transformRequest = function(data) {
      var payload = {};
      payload[namespace] = data;
      console.log(payload);
      return data;
    }

    // ngResource default actions: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L510
    actions = actions || {
      'get': {method: 'GET'},
      'save': {method: 'POST'},
      'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
      'remove': {method: 'DELETE'},
      'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
    };
    Object.keys(actions).map(function(action){
      actions[action].transformRequest = transformRequest;
    });

    return $resource(url, paramDefaults, actions, options)
  };
});
```

Then an actual factory would look like:

```
angular
  .module('myApp.users')
  .factory('User', user);

  user.$inject = ['myResource'];

  function user(myResource) {
    return myResource('user', '/users.json');
  }
```